# Can't change library version of PostgreSQL with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, macos, psycopg2

I've installed Postgresapp app with Postgresql v16 before and using it for a while. Then I realized that sometimes I'm having problems with migrations so I've tried to fix and deep into the problem. And found out that, it's using PostgreSQL client version 16 provided by Postgresapp in psycopg2, but we are using PostgreSQL 13 in production so I've decided to downgrade it in my local environment.

I've uninstalled Postgresapp and installed Postgresql v13 with brew (and also tried with PostgreSQL v13 provided in Postgresapp) but it's still looking for PostgreSQL v16 libraries, I'm getting this error.

```
  Referenced from: <6C63B347-6EF3-3651-8D8C-F7B5D56B0B8E> /Users/xxxx/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-NfM96__V-py3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-311-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/16/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/16/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/16/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

I don't want to do any hacky solution like symlinking, it's just a coverage. So how can I change this reference to the correct path? I've reinstalled postgres@13 with brew, reinstalled psycopg2, and reinstalled poetry environment but it's still looking for the wrong path.

Any suggestions?

ps: Later, I've found out that it's working with psycopg2-binary, or if I build as wheel it's working, is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Build the library from source.

Comment: Add answers to following as text update to question text. 1) What does this `I'm using v16 client with psycopg2.` mean? 2) Don't mix packaging systems e.g postgres.app and Brew. 3) What are you doing when you get the error? 4) Did you follow all the instructions here [postgres.app uninstall](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/install.html)?

Comment: updated question, and yes I've followed the uninstall steps.

Comment: It's been awhile since I was in that space, but the recommendation used to be that you should generally use psycopg2-binary

Comment: yeah, with psycopg2-binary it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I've started using psycopg2-binary, and it is working with it.